# Mosquitto ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED using websockets (paho client) on win 10

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I've read all the threads with similar questions, but couldn't find an answer.

Mosquitto config:

```
listener 1883 127.0.0.1
protocol mqtt
listener 9001 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

log output:

```
1567705166: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1567705166: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
1567705166: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1567705166: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1567705166: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1883.
```

Chrome devtools:

```
mqttws31.js:977 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've tried many things but nothing helped:

1. Trying  websockets only
2. Trying another port (1883 and 9001 instead of 8080)
3. Switching off Windows firewall

If I change the config file to:

```
#listener 1884 127.0.0.1
#protocol mqtt
#listener 1883 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

Mosquitto listens for websockets on port 1883 but logfile reads:

```
1567706943: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1567706943: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
1567706943: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1883.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
1567706943: Error in poll: No error.
```

changing config to:

```
protocol websockets
listener 8080 127.0.0.1
protocol mqtt
```

Gives me a logfile that says:

```
1567707450: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1567707450: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
1567707450: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8080.
1567707450: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1883.
```

(no extra crap)

After following up on answer no 1:

config:

```
protocol websockets
listener 1883 127.0.0.1
protocol mqtt
```

console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

log:

```
1567716915: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1567716915: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
1567716915: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1567716915: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1883.
1567716920: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1567716920: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1567716920: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1567716920: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
5492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
```

Tried another websockets client (https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/utility/) --> Failed to connect: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out.

I can't get websockets to work with any configuration / port...
Can anyone confirm that Websockets in Mosquitto (32bit version 1.6.2 or 1.6.4) for Win10 are working ?

Comment: Where did you get your Windows Mosquitto build?

Comment: Forgot where... What would be the best place to get it?

Comment: Use the official builds from mosquitto.org

Comment: Verified, I got it from there (32 bit build). Clicked on 1.6.4 but that gave me version 1.6.2 (not 1.6.4!?)

Comment: The download has now been fixed, should give 1.6.4 now

Comment: Will try 1.6.4. tomorrow

Comment: Tried Win32 1.6.4 but still got 1.6.2 when downloading. The X64 V1.6.4. crashes without any error message. The readme also states that you need to add the SLL DLL's manually, but they seem to be included in the download...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be quite the challenge.

First I tried to get things working using an online broker and client. Still not working. I then switched to another computer and everything was working fine.

Switching back to the original computer I decided to test if websockets where working at all by going to https://www.websocket.org/echo.html 
From that moment on everything started to work. First the online broker and client and then also the local server and clients. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1):

Your first config file won't work because you have both native MQTT and Websockets both trying to listen on port 1883. (this is because the default listener starts on port 1883), Not 100% sure how this is possible unless it's some strange IPv6 thing on Windows.

The second, is just changing the default listener protocol to Websockets, which in theory should work, assuming you try and connect to port 1883 from the webpage.

The third one makes the default listener on port 1883 Websockets and native on 8080. Again should work assuming you are trying to connect to 1883

The simplest config to enable Websockets should look like this:

```
listener 9001 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

This will leave the native default listener alone on port 1883 (listening on all interfaces, use `bind_address 127.0.0.1` before the `listener` line to make it only listen on localhost) and start the Websocket listener on port 9001

Comment: I have tried what you are proposing to do. This is the log file of the result (sorry for poor formatting)
1567715492: mosquitto version 1.6.2 starting
1567715492: Config loaded from C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.conf.
1567715492: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1567715492: Opening websockets listen socket on port 1883.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.
1567715492: Error in poll: No error.

Comment: The bind command yeilds an error when starting Mosquitto so I omitted it...

Comment: Respons in chrome console: WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Edit the question to add detail. Also it should have been `bind_address` not `bind`